# Will humans bow in prostration to Allah when they see Jahanam for the first time on judgement day?

Tags: forgiveness, jahannam

Is it true that on judgement day, when every soul is able to see Jahanam for the first time, that everyone will bow in prostration to Allah. But Allah will say, ‘today is not the day of repentance, it is the day of judgment’.
And is it true that non-Muslims will also perform sajdah? If so, what is the reference, thank you.

Comment: I would also like to know the reference.
This was said in a bayan.

Answer (score 3):

On judgement day all  humans are commanded to prostrate to Allah, but some are unable to do so. They are those who did not prostrate to Allah in the worldly life.

> يَوۡمَ يُكۡشَفُ عَن سَاقٖ وَيُدۡعَوۡنَ إِلَى ٱلسُّجُودِ فَلَا
> يَسۡتَطِيعُونَ 42
>
> خَٰشِعَةً أَبۡصَٰرُهُمۡ تَرۡهَقُهُمۡ ذِلَّةٞۖ وَقَدۡ
> كَانُواْ يُدۡعَوۡنَ إِلَى ٱلسُّجُودِ وَهُمۡ سَٰلِمُونَ 43
>
> Some day when their shinbone will be laid bare and they will be called
> upon to bow down on their knees, and they will not manage to; [(42)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/68/42/)
>
> with their eyes cast down, disgrace will overwhelm them. They had been
> called upon to bow down on their knees while they still felt safe.
> [(43)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/68/43/)